# Is it appropriate to edit an accepted but outdated answer to refer to another?

Tags: discussion, answers

#### [In TeXShop, is there a directive to select biber or BibTeX on a per-document basis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125712/17423)

The above answer is the 'correct' answer to the question, but the accepted answer was accepted before the feature was added to TeXShop.  Should a header be placed on the accepted answer along the lines of

> ```
> This answer was useful in previous versions of <program or package>,
> but updates have rendered this answer outdated.  Please see
> [the community-recommended answer](<link>) to this problem.
> ```

where `<link>` is a direct link to an answer on the same question.  Normally, I would say that votes are the community's way of recommending an answer, but sometimes 'hot' answers receive more votes than can be reasonably overcome by the regulars.

Comment: I think, this should be done if aware of new features. Of course, SEs take on accepted answers is the one that did help the OP most. Some highest upvoted and accepted answers on cite are even, how should i put this ... *merely hacks, not best practice at all* There are always some >20k-users in the chat room, a short not and ok might be a good idea.

Comment: @Johannes_B Naturally I'm not talking about changing which answer is accepted -- just putting a visible marker there for search-engine users. :)

Comment: Why not editing the existing answer?

Comment: @percusse This questions asks if that's appropriate. I don't think anyone would want the main content of the accepted answer to be altered, but this questions asks if the header above should be added to help point new folks to an answer below.

Comment: Why not? We do that all the time by asking the original poster, if no reaction we add an additional answer.

Comment: In this case, there is a reason to leave the original, accepted answer rather than editing it: namely, that that answer will potentially work with other editors on Mac OS X and GNU/Linux, at least. So tagging that answer as suggested seems to me potentially a better option than editing it and removing a potentially useful solution. However, it would be even better if the answer did not recommend installing the script in TEXMFMAIN.

Comment: How about adding this at the END of the answer ("$date, updated due to changed circumstances:...")? If done so, it would not "change the answer" itself, but the note will clearly stand out to $searchenginevisitors that might not read the whole article

Comment: @user2567875 To be honest, when I'm searching for an answer that involves code, I just find the gray box and copy/paste before I read anything unless it jumps out at me.